# How to stop emacs re-indenting while typing? (cc-mode)

Tags: indentation

Using C/C++ (cc-mode), emacs sometimes re-indents text as I'm typing.

For example (# for indentation, the first 4 are a tab):

```
enum {
####/
```

Typing `*`, becomes:

```
enum {
######/*
```

(inserting 2 extra spaces)

---

Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Evil.

Comment: Right, I wasn't sure when asking.

Comment: This must be a duplicate, but I don't have time to track it down. Maybe search for `electric-indent-mode`...

Comment: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31038/stop-reindenting-if-after-else/31041 is related, if not an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out [electric-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html%5Fnode/emacs/Electric-C.html) causes re-indentation, it can be disabled:

To disable, add this to your startup.

```
(when (fboundp 'electric-indent-mode) (electric-indent-mode -1))
```

---

An alternative is to disable re-indenting just for comment characters (since its handy to keep for braces).

```
;; Prefer no indentation for comment chars.
(define-key c-mode-base-map "/" 'self-insert-command)
(define-key c-mode-base-map "*" 'self-insert-command)
```