# How to NOT Auto Indent when a specific Character is inputted?

Tags: indentation, c, tabs

So I recently encountered a problem programming in C that whenever I enter the left parenthesis character, `(`, Emacs auto-idents the code.

```
[4 spaces here]DATA *SeqQueueOut(
```

I know that there is this thing called `electric-ident-mode`, which I do not want to disable it. All I want to do is to not ident the code specifically whenever I type `(`. How can I do that in `init.el`?

Comment: as isn't exactly a duplicate, check this https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/31312/11477

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>(</kbd> tells us:

```
( runs the command c-electric-paren (found in c-mode-map), which
is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘cc-cmds.el’.

It is bound to ), (.
```

I suggest:

```el
(with-eval-after-load "cc-mode"
  (define-key c-mode-map (kbd "(") #'self-insert-command)
  (define-key c-mode-map (kbd ")") #'self-insert-command))
```

Answer (score 0):

`electric-indent-mode` is enabled by default.
You can turn it off via `(electric-indent-mode -1)` in your `~/.emacs`, but if you want to only disable it for a particular char (e.g. `(`) in a particular major mode, the normal way could look like:

```
(add-hook '<foo>-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq electric-indent-chars
                  (delq ?\( electric-indent-chars))))
```

If a major mode does not obey `electric-indent-chars` I suggest you report it as a bug in that major mode (e.g. with `M-x report-emacs-bug` if it's bundled with Emacs).

Comment: cc-mode uses its own electric config here.  `c-electric-paren` says "If ‘c-syntactic-indentation’ and ‘c-electric-flag’ are both non-nil, the line is reindented unless a numeric ARG is supplied, or the parenthesis is inserted inside a literal."

Comment: See also `(ccmode)Electric Keys` and `c-toggle-electric-state`

Comment: I'm not sure it's a bug so much as a significantly older set of functionality?

Comment: @phils: It should be adapted to the new generic functionality, so it does qualify as a bug (to the extent that obeying the variable wouldn't necessarily be incompatible with its featureset).